# Regular Expression to parse SQL Structure

Tags: php, mysql, regex, types

I am trying to parse the MySQL data types returned by "DESCRIBE [TABLE]".

It returns strings like:

> int(11)
>  float
>   varchar(200)
>  int(11)
>   unsigned
>  float(6,2)

I've tried to do the job using regular expressions but it's not working.

PHP CODE:

```
$string = "int(11) numeric";<br/>
$regex = '/(\w+)\s*(\w+)/';<br/>
var_dump( preg_split($regex, $string) );<br/>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions for this? What do you want to ultimately have once you've parsed the output?

Comment: parse it how? What do you want the end result to be? The contents of the parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote code to do this in [`Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php)`::describeTable()`.
It handles varchar, char, decimal, float, and all MySQL integer types.

I won't post the code here because of StackOverflow's CC-wiki license policy, but go check it out at that link.

`mysql_fetch_field()` only reports data types for query result sets, not persisted tables.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is another option, but MySQL's early implementation of it has incredibly poor performance, which makes it hard to use in a web app that needs quick response time.  Some changes in MySQL 5.1.23 tried to improve the performance, but some people still report problems.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, does CC-wiki really conflict with the BSD license in a major way?

Comment: The CC Share-Alike license that SO uses requires attribution and it also requires that any work derived from the CC licensed code must also use a similar license.  Not a conflict per se, but it muddies the terms of use.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
I've already tested and it works PERFECTLY!

:)

Answer (score 4):

Query the [information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) for introspection of tables and columns, and more.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just pull meta-data from the fields [directly](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php)?

```
...
$meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
echo $meta->type;
echo $meta->max_length;
```